# Schema.org creator vs. author property

Tags: rdf, ontology, schema.org

It seems like they are the same?

https://schema.org/author

> The author of this content or rating. Please note that author is special in that HTML 5 provides a special mechanism for indicating authorship via the rel tag. That is equivalent to this and may be used interchangeably.

https://schema.org/creator

> The creator/author of this CreativeWork. This is the same as the Author property for CreativeWork.

I see some uses in the wild on Datasets use `author` and others `creator`.

- Are they indeed the same?
- Should one be preferred over the other?
- Are there other "aliases" in Schema.org?
- Is this notion of being the same recorded in a programmatically accessible form somewhere? (maybe in the canonical RDFa?)

Answer (score 4):

#### RDF

As of version 3.3, these two properties aren’t related/equivalent in the RDF. Here are their definitions (in Turtle RDF):

```
schema:author a rdf:Property ;
    rdfs:label "author" ;
    schema:domainIncludes schema:CreativeWork,
        schema:Rating ;
    schema:rangeIncludes schema:Organization,
        schema:Person ;
    rdfs:comment "The author of this content or rating. Please note that author is special in that HTML 5 provides a special mechanism for indicating authorship via the rel tag. That is equivalent to this and may be used interchangeably." .
```

```
schema:creator a rdf:Property ;
    rdfs:label "creator" ;
    schema:domainIncludes schema:CreativeWork,
        schema:UserComments ;
    schema:rangeIncludes schema:Organization,
        schema:Person ;
    rdfs:comment "The creator/author of this CreativeWork. This is the same as the Author property for CreativeWork." .
```

As can be seen, they don’t refer to each other on the RDF-level. The sentence ("This is the same as the Author property for CreativeWork.") in the human-readable definition of `creator` is the only place that says that these two properties are equivalent.

#### Differences

While both properties can be used for `CreativeWork` items, only `author` can be used for `Rating` items, and only `creator` can be used for `UserComments` items.

#### Which to use?

As [`UserComments`](https://schema.org/UserComments) shouldn’t be used anymore, the `author` property would be the more useful one if you only ever want to use one of the two properties.

However, as the `CreativeWork` type is not only for works that have, in the natural langauge sense, an *author* (documents etc.), but also for works that have a *creator* (e.g., sculptures, for which there is the [`Sculpture`](https://schema.org/Sculpture) type), authors of the structured data might want to prefer the `creator` property in these cases.

Anyway, in Microdata and RDFa, it’s easy to use both:

```html
<span itemprop="author creator"></span>
```

```html
<span property="author creator"></span>
```

(You can use both in JSON-LD, too, of course, but it’s not *that* simple.)

So if you care about the RDF, and until Schema.org makes these two properties equivalent on the RDF-level (if ever), you might want go this way if you think that an interested consumer only supports one of these two properties.